# How to output which line in the textfile where the program found an Index error?

Tags: python, index-error

How to retrieve the line at which the exception is thrown?

```py
def openfile(which_file): #Funktion som öppnar och läser den valda filen rad för rad
    with open(which_file, "r") as file:
        file_rows=file.readlines()
        passengers=[]
        for lines in file_rows:
            try:
                if lines !="\n":     #Här används klassen data_manager:
                    objekt=carclass.data_manager(lines.split()[0], lines.split()[1], lines.split()[2], lines.split()[9], lines.split()[13], lines.split()[-1])
                    passengers.append(objekt)
            except IndexError:
                print("Wrong registration at line") #WHICH LINE?
        return passengers
```

Comment: `for line_num, lines in enumerate(file_rows):`

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you please clearify it more? (Maybe by writing what I will print etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to index the lines

```py
with open(...) as fh:
    for index, line in enumerate(fh):
        ...
```

do note that

- file-likes are already iterable by-lines, so you don't need to read the whole file into memory before working with it (ie. `.readlines()`)
- `enumerate()` indexes from zero, while files are commonly talked about starting from "Line 1", so it's often convenient to add 1 to the index when displaying (or give enumerate a starting value of 1, though this will likely lead to worse confusion)

---

For your case, this probably looks like

```py
passengers=[]
with open(which_file) as fh:
    for index, line in enumerate(fh):
        atoms = line.split()
        if not atoms or len(atoms) < 14:  # TBD
            print(f"error at line {index+1}: {line}")
        passengers.append(
            carclass.data_manager(
                atoms[0],
                atoms[1],
                atoms[2],
                atoms[9],
                atoms[13],
                atoms[-1]
            )
        )
return passengers
```